# iOS Share Extension kUTTypeMovie get thumbnail

Tags: ios, share-extension

Hey there i am having trouble while sharing video from photos using my share extension. My problem is that i wanted to get the thumbnail & size of the video in my share extension hosted by Photos app.
Any help is appreciable, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

UIViewController of Share Extension have a property:

```
    NSExtensionContext *extensionContext;
```

NSExtensionContext have a property:

```
    NSArray *inputItems;
```

Which have a 0-indexed object of NSExtensionItem class

Next, NSExtension Item have a property:

```
    NSArray *attachments;
```

Which is an array of objects of NSItemProvider class, and now it is time to go to read some [documentation for NSItemProvider class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsitemprovider)

Comment: Do you need to loop through all the items until you find the thumbnails?

Comment: no, he just need to get an object of NSItemProvider class, here is the way to do it. Later on he should check if NSItemProvider "hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier" (to kUTTypeMovie, for example), and this class able to return thumbnail for item.

Comment: but actually he should iterate over attachments array of NSItemProvider objects, to figure out, which one is a video there. if count is more than one.